# AmCharts. Aligning balloons

Tags: amcharts

I've spent a lot of time finding the solution, but i can't see any property in AmChatrts documentation that can align balloons not vertically. Actually, I just want to see all balloons, but not in one column. Can anybody help me?

[image: amcharts example]

Comment: How would you rather like them to be positioned?

Comment: No matter how exactly. The main problem is that they don't fit chart's height. Some of then are hidden because they are below the chart screen

Answer (score 4):

There is currently no way to make the balloons stack in any different way than in once column. However, there are a few alternatives you can consider.

---

1) Displaying just one balloon.

To do that, set [`oneBalloonOnly`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ChartCursor#oneBalloonOnly) to `true`:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv",{
  ...
  "chartCursor": {
    "oneBalloonOnly": true
  }
});
```

This will make the cursor display just one balloon of the closest graph.

---

2) Disable balloons and use a [`legend`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend) instead.

To disable balloons, simply set [`valueBalloonsEnabled][3]` in chart cursor's settings to `false`.

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv",{
  ...
  "chartCursor": {
    "valueBalloonsEnabled": false
  },
  "legend": {}
});
```

The legend will show relative value next to each graph title when you hover over the chart.

---

3) Consolidate values from multiple graphs into a single balloon.

To do that, use graph's [`balloonText`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#balloonText) property. It lets you reference to any field in data, so you can make it display values from any graph.

Here's a [good example](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/7230cf601e427728682caf8bf5498f3b) of the above.

Here's a good demo on how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for help. I'm already using a legend and I've seen this demo. But I have a Stock Chart with dataSetSelector from several dataProviders, so I don't know how to get values in property "BalloonText" from currently selected providers

Comment: Well, in that case you should probably look into `balloonFunction` instead. http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/StockGraph#balloonFunction